# triggering nodejs function from mssql table insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I want to setup a trigger on inserts that occur to a datbase table inside a Microsoft SQL Server environment.

What is the best method to have the trigger call an external nodejs script.

Do I just have it exec a script direct from MSSQL trigger?

Just looking for different ideas on implementation approach.

I need to have the trigger exec my outside script in real-time at the exact moment of the trigger event.

Thx

Comment: Seems a bit off to need to run a node script while inserting to the database. You would have to do this with CLR. There is nothing native in t-sql that I know of that can run a node script.

Comment: i want to run some code in node that will run at the exact moment the insert is completed on the table. I can also consider doing this with C# and use the EdgeJS library to bridge to Node

Comment: Yeah I got that from your question. I was saying that seems pretty odd to me but whatever.

Comment: The use case is not typical

Comment: Curious, what is the use case for this?

Comment: desktop .net based desktop app stores records to mssql. No native API , i need a way to catch the event at the exact moment of insertion into db and take the new stored records data and perform some additional routines via my own external outside "plugin". i'm open to any ideas

Comment: Like I said, pretty much no option but CLR which you can execute in a trigger.

Comment: You could write a message to a service broker queue in the trigger, with a node.js service listening for messages as the external activated service.

Comment: @Dan Guzman I like your thinking! Any suggestions on the service broker ... are you thinking like RabbitMQ ?

Comment: another option i was testing was using the EXEC xp_cmdshell feature .. it runs synchronously but it does seem to trigger my nodejs script

Comment: Service Broker is a feature built into the SQL Server database engine. The trigger could `SEND` a message to the node service asynchronously. The node service could `RECEIVE` messages (via a proc call) and perform additional processing needed. There is a bit a learning curve since SB doesn't fit the relational database paradigm and queues are somewhat abstracted via services. It's important to follow vetted patterns.

Comment: Note that the trigger runs in a transaction so data modified by statement that fired the trigger wouldn't be committed when the process launched via xp_cmdshell executes.